# RDS access via IAM role from a Golang microservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I was implementing RDS IAM authentication from my Golang service and came across an issue. I am using the init function to call create a function where I have created a sync for every 10 mins where every 10 mins the token should get refreshed, it is creating the new token but it's not passing the same to the main function. When the existing thread that was initiated between DB and the service gets killed it is unable to re-authenticate the connection for the second time. Some observations that I have noticed were-
When initially deploying the application it is creating the connection to RDS successfully but after some time as soon as the initial thread between service and DB gets killed it's unable to authenticate the reason which I checked was- the address where the token is getting stored. While making an API call the service picks the token from a static address where the initial token gets stored at the time of service deployment. However, while the token gets refreshed every 10 mins its getting stored on dynamic addresses from where the service is unable to pick up the token.

Here is the go file where actually I am calling and creating the DB function-

```golang
package db

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/rds/rdsutils"
    "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const DatabaseVersion = 1

const Success = "Database connection successful"
const database = "postgres"

// Service ...
type Service interface {
    InitDatabaseConnection(db **gorm.DB)
    CreateDatabaseConnection(db **gorm.DB)
    Migrate(db *gorm.DB) error
}

type service struct {
}

// NewService ...
func NewService() Service {
    return &service{}
}
func (s *service) InitDatabaseConnection(db **gorm.DB) {
    log.Print("Creating Db Connection")
    s.CreateDatabaseConnection(db)
    //todo: add if; if env for iam run the below code
    // todo: change 1 min to 10 mins
    startTime := time.Now().Local().Add(time.Minute + time.Duration(1))
    sch := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
    sch.Every(600).Seconds().StartAt(startTime).Do(func() {
        log.Printf("refreshing rds creds")
        s.CreateDatabaseConnection(db)
    })
    sch.StartAsync()
}

func (s *service) CreateDatabaseConnection(db **gorm.DB) {
    configuration, _ := common.New()
    var dbURI = ConnectDataBase(configuration.UserName, configuration.Password,
        configuration.Port, configuration.DbName, configuration.Host, configuration.SearchPath)
    var err error
    *db, err = gorm.Open(database, dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    print("\n \n", dbURI)
    print("\n \n in server.go \n \n ", &db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(3)
    } else {
        log.Println(Success)
    }
    (*db).DB().SetMaxOpenConns(6)
    (*db).DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(600 * time.Second)
    (*db).DB().SetMaxIdleConns(2)
    (*db).DB().SetConnMaxIdleTime(100 * time.Second)
}

func ConnectDataBase(username string, password string, port int, dbName string, host string, searchPath string) string {
    var dbURI string
    if searchPath == "" {
        searchPath = "public"
    }
    dbEndpoint := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port)
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    creds := sess.Config.Credentials
    authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(dbEndpoint, "us-east-1", username, creds)
    print("\n \n", authToken)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dbURI = fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require password=%s search_path=%s",
        host, port, username, dbName, authToken, searchPath) //Build connection string
    // if password != "" && username != "" {
    //  dbURI = fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require password=%s search_path=%s",
    //      host, port, username, dbName, authToken, searchPath) //Build connection string
    // } else {
    //  dbURI = fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d dbname=%s sslmode=disable ",
    //      host, port, dbName) //Build connection string
    // }
    return dbURI
}

func (s *service) Migrate(db *gorm.DB) error {
    migrationSourceURL := "file://../resources/db/migrations/"
    database := db.DB()

    row := db.Table("schema_migrations").Limit(1).Row()
    var version int8
    var dirty bool

    err := row.Scan(&version, &dirty)
    if err == nil {
        log.Printf("database is currently on version : %v \n", version)
    }

    log.Println("Migrating database to version ", DatabaseVersion)
    driver, err := postgres.WithInstance(database, &postgres.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    m, err := migrate.NewWithDatabaseInstance(migrationSourceURL, "postgres", driver)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    m.Log = LogService{}
    err = m.Migrate(uint(DatabaseVersion))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

The common property above is from this piece of code-

```golang
package common

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type ApiResponse struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type Constants struct {
    Port         int    `json:"port"`
    Host         string `json:"host"`
    DbName       string `json:"dbName"`
    UserName     string `json:"userName"`
    Password     string `json:"password"`
    AuthUserName string `json:"authUserName"`
    AuthPassword string `json:"authPassword"`
    SearchPath   string `json:"searchPath"`
    AwsRegion    string `json:"awsRegion"`
}

func New() (*Constants, error) {
    fmt.Println("reached constants")
    config := Constants{}
    constants, err := initViper()
    config = constants
    if err != nil {
        return &config, err
    }

    return &config, nil
}

func initViper() (Constants, error) {
    // temporary, will be removed later when auto deploy is available
    env := os.Getenv("CS_ENV")
    var configName string
    if env == "develop" {
        configName = "config-develop"
    } else {
        configName = "config-local"
    }

    viper.SetConfigName(configName)            // Constants fileName without the .TOML or .YAML extension
    viper.AddConfigPath("../resources/config") // Search the root directory for the configuration file
    err := viper.ReadInConfig()                // Find and read the config file
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error()) // Handle errors reading the config file
        return Constants{}, err
    }
    if err = viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("Error reading config file, %s", err)
    }

    var constants Constants
    err = viper.Unmarshal(&constants)
    return constants, err
}
```

Also attaching the main function go file where I am calling the DB function for connecting the service to DB-

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    gokitlog "github.com/go-kit/kit/log"
    "github.com/go-kit/kit/log/level"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func runServer(config *common.Constants) {
    var logger gokitlog.Logger
    logger = gokitlog.NewLogfmtLogger(gokitlog.NewSyncWriter(os.Stderr))
    logger = gokitlog.With(logger, "ts", gokitlog.DefaultTimestampUTC)

    dbService := db2.NewService()
    var db *gorm.DB
    dbService.InitDatabaseConnection(&db)

    err := dbService.Migrate(db)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Migrations scripts did not run :", err.Error())
        if err.Error() != "no change" {
            fmt.Println("failed to run migrations hence exiting", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
    level.Info(logger).Log("Starting Darwin ==========>")

    repo, err := allocation.NewUserAllocationRepository(db, logger)
    if err != nil {
        level.Error(logger).Log("exit", err)
        os.Exit(3)
    }
    userAllocationService := allocation.NewUserAllocationService(repo, logger)

    endpoints := allocation.MakeEndpoints(userAllocationService)

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    sh := http.StripPrefix("/swaggerui/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("../resources/swaggerui/")))
    router.PathPrefix("/swaggerui/").Handler(sh)
    httpLogger := gokitlog.With(logger, "component", "http")
    subRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()
    subRouter.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(notFound)
    subRouter.Use(checkBasicAuth(config))
    subRouter.HandleFunc("/healthCheck", healthCheck).Methods("GET")
    allocation.MakeHandler(subRouter, httpLogger, endpoints)
    http.Handle("/", subRouter)

    log.Print("Running server on port 8080")
    f, err := os.OpenFile("../performance.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error opening file: %v", err)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
    } else {
        by := bufio.NewWriter(f)
        defer f.Close()
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", Logger(by, router)))
    }
}

func healthCheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    resp := map[string]string{
        "Status": "Success",
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
}

func notFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"error": "api not found"})
}

func authHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"error": "Not authorized"})
}

func checkBasicAuth(config *common.Constants) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            if r.URL.RequestURI() != "/api/v1/healthCheck" {
                w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Restricted"`)
                w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;")
                s := strings.SplitN(r.Header.Get("Authorization"), " ", 2)
                if len(s) != 2 {
                    authHandler(w, r)
                    return
                }
                b, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s[1])
                if err != nil {
                    authHandler(w, r)
                    return
                }
                pair := strings.SplitN(string(b), ":", 2)
                if len(pair) != 2 {
                    authHandler(w, r)
                    return
                }
                if pair[0] != config.AuthUserName || pair[1] != config.AuthPassword {
                    authHandler(w, r)
                    return
                }
            }
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

func Logger(out *bufio.Writer, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    logger := log.New(out, "", 0)
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        o := &responseObserver{ResponseWriter: w, status: http.StatusOK}
        start := time.Now()
        h.ServeHTTP(o, r)
        endTime := time.Now()
        if !strings.Contains(r.URL.String(), "/health") && strings.Contains(r.URL.String(), "/api") {
            logger.Printf("Method: %s Path: %s Status: %d ExecutionTime: %d ms", r.Method, r.URL, o.status, endTime.Sub(start).Milliseconds())
            out.Flush()
        }
    })
}

type responseObserver struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    status int
}

func (r *responseObserver) WriteHeader(status int) {
    r.status = status
    r.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(status)
}
```

Comment: One thing I see in your code is`startTime := time.Now().Local().Add(time.Minute + time.Duration(1))` and `sch := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)`. You are starting the scheduler in UTC but giving the start time in your local timezone. It could be that the timer does not start for a few hours (depending on your timezone) and hence no token is generated.

Comment: The local time is getting picked up from the instance, and the instance is running using UTC only. And the token is getting refreshed every time. We have checked that already. @TobiasPfandzelter